# How to get a virt size from C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, linux, memory-management

Is there a simply way how to get the virt size of the Linux process from the C/C++ code? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to find out your the virtual size of own process you simply need to read `/proc/self/status` and find there the VmSize field

```
FILE* handle = fopen("/proc/self/status","r");
// and then read its conttent find the VmSize string and its value
```

If you want to know the virtual size of an arbitrary process then open `"/proc/<process-id>/status"` for the process and find there the VmSize field.

Comment: Thank you, I used this solution.

Answer (score 1):

The most portable way is with `getrusage()` (see [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/2/getrusage)) although if if your application is truly Linux specific then the suggested alternative of parsing `/proc/self/status` is just as good.